# Laravel Sessions and Guzzle

Tags: php, session, laravel, redis, guzzle

I have a queue worker which rebuilds the cache for some 50 routes every time a user submits or updates an "item". In the worker I'm calling these routes with Guzzle which works fine. My cache and session storage is Redis. However, Guzzle seems to create a new session for each request it makes, so my Redis database gets filled with unnecessary session data from Guzzle.

Is there a workaround or should I just don't care about it? I tried to disable cookies in Guzzle, but this didn't work. My session lifetime is set to 1 day.